# how to prove this ? (continuity of 2 variable function)

Tags: calculus, limits

> Prove that 
>   $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{2x^2+|y^3|}$$
>   does not exist. (or exists)

I don't know what to do.

I've already checked following paths
$y=mx$,
$y=e^x-1$, and
$y=mx^k$ (when $k$ is positive real number)

Comment: I notice that none of your attempts try the vertical line $x=0$.

Comment: I think it's obvious that the value is 0 when the path is x=0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try with polar coordinates:

$$\begin{cases}x=r\cos t\\{}\\y=r\sin t\end{cases}\;\implies\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{xy^2}{2x^2+|y^3|}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^3\cos t\sin^2t}{2r^2\cos^2t+|r^3\sin^3t|}=$$

$$=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r\cos t\sin^2t}{2\cos^2t+r|\sin^3t|}=0$$

and the denominator cannot equal zero as is a sum of non-negatives and cosine and sine don't vanish simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use squeeze method
\begin{align}
0< \Big |  \frac{xy^2}{2x^2+ |y^3|} \Big |  &= \Big |  \frac{x|y^{3/2}|}{2x^2+ |y^3|} \Big | |y|^{1/2} \leq |y|^{1/2} 
\end{align}
where I used $\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2} \leq 1$ for the upper bound. Hence taking the limit you'll have
$$
\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \Big |  \frac{xy^2}{2x^2+ |y^3|} \Big | =0
$$

Comment: thx! it helped a lot